# showing the incrementation of i in tkinter gui

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I want to show the incrementation of i in the Tkinter GUI.

```
import sys
import os
import cv2
import xlsxwriter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("400x200")
gui.title("gui")
gui.iconbitmap('a.ico')
status = Label(gui, text="status", relief=FLAT)
status.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W+E)
class FolderSelect(Frame):
    get the path for the specified directories

def doStuff():
    get the directories and call the other function test



folderPath = StringVar()

directory1Select = FolderSelect(gui,"1    ")
directory1Select.grid(row=0)

directory2Select = FolderSelect(gui,"2     ")
directory2Select.grid(row=1)

directory3Select = FolderSelect(gui,"3")
directory3Select.grid(row=2)


c = ttk.Button(gui, text="Start", command=doStuff)
c.grid(row=4,column=0)


def test():
   get folders, get paths, do stuff

    i = 0 

    
do alot of stuff

        i += 1

        status = Label(gui, text="Done", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
        status.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W+E)
        

            
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output + '/result2.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    row = 1
    col = 0

    worksheet.write(0, 0, "1")
    worksheet.write(0, 1, "2")
    worksheet.write(0, 2, "3")
    worksheet.write(0, 3, "4")

    for 1, 2, 3, 4 in result:
        worksheet.write(row, col, 1)
        worksheet.write(row, col + 1, str(2))
        worksheet.write(row, col + 2, str(3))
        worksheet.write(row, col + 3, str(4) + "%")
        row += 1

    workbook.close()





gui.mainloop()
```

I have tried the following:

```
i += 1
status = Label(gui, text="Nr " + str(i) + " of " + str(len(ls_imgs1_names)), bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
```

But it updates the gui only when the code finishes. For example it freezes as long as the loop is going and when it stops it shows "Nr 10 of 10". I want the incrementation to be in real time like "1 of 10", "2 of 10"..."10 of 10".

Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding `status.update()` after `status.grid(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked with status.update().

Thanks @acw1668!